# In TF, what the tensor automatically named Conv2DBackpropInput represents?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Does it represent the output of the Conv2D block in the backward pass?

Or the input of the Conv2D block in the backward pass?

Comment: It will be helpful if you could post the code which automatically names the tensor ( the model's code probably ).

Comment: I have included a little more detail in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234649/what-is-the-position-of-the-tensor-where-relu-in-forward-and-conv2dbackpropinp